# attr_reader in ruby API wrappers

Tags: ruby, api

I'm creating an API wrapper for reddit for fun using other clients like the `twitter` gem, `redditkit` and `octokit.rb`, which all use models with `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor` for users to be able to access the attributes stored in a hash.

Is there any standard or reason why the return values need to be explicitly stated in the model rather than have a `method_missing` that fetches the values from the hash? Why does it need to be like this:

```
class Something
  def self.attr_reader(meth)
    define_method(meth) { @attributes[meth] }
  end

  attr_reader :thing1
  attr_reader :thing2
  attr_reader :tedium
  ...
```

rather than

```
class Something
  def method_missing(meth, args)
    if @attributes.has_key?(meth)
      @attributes[meth]
    else
      send(:meth, *args)
    end
  end
```

Comment: -1. Your definition of `method_missing` is ungrammatical. A method cannot accept a symbol `:meth` as a variable name (unless for named parameters), and it will not work for attr reader methods also because you would be passing zero arguments, but the expected arguments would be one. And by the way, what is `@attributes`? Do not introduce a variable without explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_reader` does not implement the getter by returning `@attributes[:thing]`, but rather returning `@thing`. It is safe to use (you get only what you declare - malicious code cannot hide its own data in your object, etc.).

If you want an object which has totally dynamic attributes, there are implementations for it (like [`OpenStruct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)), or you can simply work directly with `Hash`es...

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all. It may better be a comment.

Comment: @sawa The OP question (as I understand it) is `Why does it need to be like this?` (= because it is safe) `rather than [that]?` (= if this is what you need there are simpler options)

Comment: Is your answer "It is safe to use"?

Comment: @sawa - `It is safe to use (you get only what you declare - malicious code cannot hide its own data in your object, etc.).`

Comment: My bad - the libraries actually redefined attr_reader to return @attributes[:thing].